# What do I do when I see an answer consisting of basically the same code in the question?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, first-post-review

Recently I faced two cases in the "First posts" review queue where the answer (the post which needs a review) was containing only code. But the problem is that this code was literally copied from the question and the answerer did not even change any character. In the first case, I flagged the post as spam because I thought this will be the best decision but the flag has been declined. In the second case, I flagged the post as a very low-quality post but it was declined as well as the first one.

What should I do to remove these useless posts?

Here are links to the posts that my flags has been declined:

- [Flickity slider with shopify liquid with add initialIndex from shopify theme code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022649/flickity-slider-with-shopify-liquid-with-add-initialindex-from-shopify-theme-cod/68408824#68408824)
- [Submit form without form id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082572/submit-form-without-form-id/68194837#68194837)

Comment: "*In the first case I flaged this post as a spam*" it's not spam. It's not *advertising* anything.

Comment: Well, then I ask what do I do. Which flag should I use to make this post deleted? I guess you agree that this answer should be deleted.

Comment: Downvote (optionally comment) and move on. Simples. Flagging is not required.

Comment: "Not an answer" seems applicable. You can most definitely downvote the answers as not useful, as well.

Comment: "Not an Answer" is unlikely to be accepted as a flag. It IS an answer, just not a good one.

Comment: @Paulie_D the flag description says "does not attempt to answer the question" and indeed it doesn't. It's not a "bad" answer as much as no answer at all.

Comment: @VLAZ It may be an Answer to some post.. which on Stack Overflow makes it an attempt to answer. Perhaps raising an "in need of moderator intervention" flag and explain that it's a pure copy of the code in the Question is the best bet for handling it?

Comment: @VLAZ It's definitely not an answer and there's no question about that. However, it _is_ quite likely that a mod will decline the flag because _it looks like an answer_.

Comment: Perhaps you could post del-pls requests for them on [socvr](https://socvr.org/).

Comment: So, you finally found the conundrum. You found a post that deserves deletion but you don't have any tooling that allows you to signal other users to actually delete it. On any other site, any flag would have deleted this, because a moderator or user would try to figure out why this answer was flagged and see that it's exactly the same content as the question and recognize that this post should be deleted. But on SO, any post with the most superficial resemblance to anything that could be an answer wouldn't get deleted without 20k users picking the slack.

Comment: @Braiam There's a good reason for this. Flagging this "Not an Answer" and letting moderators make guesses as to why it was flagged wastes a lot of time. There's no reason why the flagger should withhold the information that they gained. No reason why they don't raise a custom flag and explain what they know.

Comment: Flagging as "not an answer" is possible, but you should leave a comment first to explain why the answer post is bad. Then the reviewers can take that comment into consideration.

Comment: @VLAZ: Good point, we should really get SO to change the wording on those flags based on how mods handle them in practice: if something even looks like it might be an answer to *some* question, that's the wrong flag, and it would be less frustrating if the wording reflected that.

Comment: @PeterCordes rather than that, we should get moderators to handle flags how every site handles them. Using exactly the same text it has. SO shouldn't ask for a special flag text based on brain dead interpretation of the text of the flag.

Comment: @Scratte well, then leave those posts to the reviewers to handle them without intervention. They are many more and only need to handle at most 40 posts. Or lets get more moderators. Someone flag shouldn't be declined if the post needs deletion. Because at the end, what message are we sending? That we allow crap on the site?

Comment: @Braiam There's a message in [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). It's loud and very clear. Trying to change that by bending the rules isn't going to make things better. Let Subject Matters Experts decide what to delete in case there's confusion, or raise a custom moderator flag.

Comment: @Scratte Yeah, [it's a substantially worse message than the original:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/213575) use your brain.

Comment: I would like to point out that I have seen multiple instances of questions where the correct answer actually *was* the code from the question. In all cases, the OP had asked "How can I write something like this", sketching out the code they wanted to write, and in all cases, the sketch they made *was* exactly "how you can write something like this" … they just never bothered to try whether what they had written actually worked.

Comment: @JörgWMittag then you can just leave a comment that in your opinion it is going to work properly or as expected. You can even post an answer where you inform the OP that this code is quite good or add some tips for him. But coping the whole code from the question, not adding anything from you and not changing literally any character is just spam in my opinion. Answer like this doesn't add anything new to the question and it should be deleted.

Comment: @PeterCordes almost everything is an answer to *some* question, such as "can you please retype the code in the question?" or "which company do you work for and why are their products awesome?" or "which letters do you get when you mash the keyboard?"

Comment: @blazej You're not wrong in general, knowing that "spam" can mean several things in the wonderful world of the internet. In forums and chat it is often used to imply repeated posting of useless and disruptive junk. But in the context of Stack Overflow, it refers to the email kind of spam. Viagra pills and all that. You should hopefully only very rarely have to use it.

Comment: @IanKemp Moderators are users too. Its takes a minute to write what's wrong with a post. It takes much longer to guess and investigate. It doesn't matter how you spin it, there's only so much time in a day and only so many moderator hours. And teaching people to be upfront with information is hardly a bad thing.

Comment: @Scratte Guess what, basic usability doesn't care that "it only takes a minute". If an action takes one more *click* than it needs, a vast majority of users are not going to do it, simple as that. Which means garbage that should be getting flagged isn't getting flagged, which means it's not getting removed, *which is an abject failure on every conceivable level*.

Comment: @IanKemp I don't think anyone is claiming that the situation is ideal, but it is what it is. If you feel strongly that the way NAA flags are handled should be changed, or that there needs to be some modification to how poor content should be flagged/handled by users, I suggest making another meta post about it (check for dupes first, of course). This particular question is asking about what should be done, *given the current situation*. Complaining that the current situation is abject (valid though that may be) on this thread, is fairly pointless, and somewhat tangential to the discussion.

Comment: @user253751: Yes, off-topic and useless questions constructed like that could have that as an answer.  But in that case the whole question should be deleted.  Mods can see the question title easily enough while handling NAA flags, I think.  Related: [Not-an-answer flag declined on an answer that's clearly a comment on the programming language/CPU design, not an answer to any programming question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409213) for a case where I thought it couldn't be the answer to any question, without realizing that conclusion depended on some technical expertise.

Comment: @PeterCordes You suggested we shouldn't delete an answer if the answer could possibly answer *any question*. That is incorrect. Every answer answers some question.

Comment: @user253751: "Some question" was (clearly IMO) intended to mean "some (valid) SO question", because we're talking about Stack Overflow.  A "thanks" answer can be the answer to "please thank me for my awesomeness", but clearly mods have no problem deleting those answers in practice when people correctly flag them as NAA.  Also, I never said we shouldn't *delete* answers that look like they could be SO answers, just that we should flag them differently (custom flag instead of NAA).  Anyway, sometimes being concise takes priority over ruling out every possible weird semantic interpretation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest option when faced with this kind of answer is to simply downvote the answer. This is a good signal to future readers that the answer is not useful. You could also optionally leave a comment stating that the answer simply repeats the code in the question.

I would agree that the answer is useless enough that it should be removed from the site, even though it's not causing any harm *per se*. If you have the privilege to delete answers (and it's negatively scored, which is almost certainly the case), go ahead and cast a delete vote. The answer will probably show up in the 10k tools, where other users may cast a delete vote as well.

You could ask a moderator to delete it, by raising a flag. Note that none of the standard flags apply here; it's definitely not spam (or R/A), it's not VLQ, and it's not NAA (it's definitely an answer, just a useless one), which are the usual flags used for removing content. Raising a custom flag saying "The answer repeats *exactly* the code in the question, and adds nothing new. It should be deleted", has a reasonable chance of being accepted, although moderators generally prefer not to have to intervene in cases where the community can deal with it.

If you want to increase the chances that the answer is deleted by the community, you could post a `del-pls` in the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570). Make sure to read the [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq), which has guidance on when, and how, requests should be posted.

Comment: *not causing any harm per se* - if it's dissuading people from even looking at the question (e.g i prioritize "0 answer unanswered" over "1 answer unanswered" on the dashboard) then i'd say it could be considered harmful

Comment: Why not NAA? Certainly "repeating the question" counts as "not attempting to answer the question", right?

Comment: @TheDIMMReaper Yes, but it requires looking at the question to know that the answer is repeating the code in the question. *Do not* raise a NAA flag if it requires looking at the question to assess that an answer is, in fact, not an answer.

Comment: I would add a comment (I believe mods can read) explaining why I flagged it and flag as NAA. Without comment it's indeed hard to judge, I've seen many "Try this" answers consisting of dozens lines of code copied from the question and then a tiny change in one line.

Comment: @jps No, that's not going to work either, since mods don't generally read comments at all when evaluating NAA flags. In fact, AFAIK, the *only* context that mods are guaranteed to have when evaluating NAA is *other* flags on the answer. You might want to take a look at this recent [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409213) about NAA flags that was answered by a mod, which should address some of your concerns.

Comment: @cigien A copy/paste section of the question with no changes is "obviously irrelevant to the question".  Determining it is NAA requires zero domain specific knowledge.  It would require reading the reason why it is NAA, which is apparently behind the moderator's time budget for handling NAA flags.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I never claimed that any domain specific knowledge is required, I'm only claiming that the question needs to be read to determine if the answer is a copy-paste of the question, and that's *not* something mods are in the habit of doing when handling NAA flags. There's very good reasons BTW for why NAAs need to be obvious; if mods have to evaluate NAAs thoroughly by looking at all the context, there would be no way of clearing the NAA flag queue, which is much worse.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the usage guidance around the "not an answer" flag is pants-on-head retarded.

What a *reasonable* person would do is look at a so-called "answer", see it's evidently not an answer to the question posed, and click the flag, at which point they're presented with this dialog:

[image]

And hey, guess what, there's a convenient option that says "not an answer" *right there*, and its flavour text says **exactly what the problem is**:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

So a reasonable person will select that option, click the "flag answer" button, go on their merry way thinking they've done their good deed for the day... and a few hours later, get a notice that their flag has been declined.

**That is not reasonable in any way shape or form.** The user followed the instructions given to them by the system to curate content, and the system rejected them when they helped.

Forget about non-confrontational language and correct pronoun use - if **anything** on Stack Overflow contradicts the "be nice" ethos, it's this absolutely *shameful* situation of people trying to be helpful, and being told their help is not wanted.

The sad part is that, despite the recurring questions on this insanity on Meta, users - including many longstanding ones - just take it for granted that the system is broken and don't bother explaining that, instead focusing on telling incredulous users "this is insane, but you should just get used to it".

The meta questions generated by the Not An Answer flag are an X-Y problem if I've ever seen one. When are we going to focus on the X instead of the Y? When are we going to accept that being nice to users starts with *making a logical system*?

Comment: This is a valid point, but as I mentioned in a comment to you on the question, this should be a separate Meta post, right? I mean, this isn't even answering the OP's question; at no point did they raise a NAA flag that got declined. You could literally lift this into its own question about how NAA flags are handled, and you would be able to get responses there. (Also, you might want to suggest concrete fixes for the problem).

Comment: _Forget about non-confrontational language and correct pronoun use - if anything on Stack Overflow contradicts the "be nice" ethos, it's this absolutely shameful situation of people trying to be helpful, and being told their help is not wanted._ ---> Declining flags is not rude in any way. I find this answer to not answer the question and it is also written as a rant. This is simply a rant about something you are frustrated about and doesn't actually address the specific question at hand.

Answer (score -1):

It is obviously not a spam. It is just non-answer. Copying back exactly the same code of the question, without any text, obviously does not qualify as "attempt to answer".

Note, even if the code is not exactly the same, but there is no textual reply, the answer almost surely qualifies as VLQ.

Spam would require advertisement. It is not advertisement, only crap.

The difference is the input we give to possible anti-spam algorithms, and that the OP deserves -100 or not.

Comment: Not spam in the strictest sense, but can easily be part of spamming. Many spammers these days are aware that brand-new accounts attract more scrutiny and try to circumvent that by starting out with a few non-advertising posts. In some cases they'll go back and edit the spam in later, since a late edit often gets less scrutiny than the original answer.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Wow, it is very "funny"! Well, another threat: maybe editing spam into the posts of *others*, would likely result that they get the -100 and not the spammer.

Comment: @peterh a spammer would hardly get the 2000 rep required to be able to freely edit other peoples posts.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Wow, tricky guys! That charcoal thing is not so bad idea.