# Aren't we supposed to get rid of answers that address a comment rather than the original question?

Tags: support, answers, declined-flags

Today I found an answer that answers a follow-up question made by the OP in a comment under the question.

According to [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412159/how-should-i-handle-answers-that-address-a-comment-rather-than-the-original-ques), it seems the community consensus is that this type of answers are not considered valid and we can/should get rid of them.

The answer was literally formatted as:

> Question in the question's comments [with link], above
>
> > <quote of the question in the comment>
>
> <Answer of quoted question in the quote>

I thought that would be enough of a context to make it work as a NAA flag. It was not and it was declined - but I'm ok with that (kinda...). What puzzles me is why a subsequent mod flag I raised got declined too. The flag I raised was phrased as:

> I thought it was obvious enough so raised an NAA flag but that got
> declined... Anyway, this answer doesn't answer the question at all. It
> is answering a follow-up question made by the OP in a comment: <quote
> of question in comments>. The main question is not about that, it is
> about <subject of question>

The comment-question wasn't narrowing down or clarifying the main question. The main question was kinda solved by a comment (wrong in itself but nevermind) and then the OP asked a follow-up as another comment.

Am I wrong that such answer should be deleted?

Comment: I'm gonna need to see this in context.  Sounds like this is an awkward case.

Comment: @Makoto Yes it is. I was trying to keep it away from the meta effect and put all necessary information here but I can see how it might get *too* generic

Comment: Yeah, fair enough.  I can't say that there's a generic-enough stance we could take in a situation like this.  It seems like there was some conflation to what led to the comment being asked in the first place (chameleon question?) and what the mod likely saw in-context (an answer that looks like an answer or is plausibly an answer to a question).

Comment: Well it *was* an answer. To the question posted as a comment. And it was very clearly admitted in the answer itself so I thought it would be enough to go on. But I guess it comes down to subject matter knowledge of the mod to determine how much the comment is related or not to the original question and hence making the answer delete-worthy or not

Comment: Is there any particular reason why it needed to be deleted immediately via a mod (read: flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention), and it couldn't be handled through del-votes?

Comment: @Nick Well I don't have the ability to cast delete votes and as such using mod flags is my only way of getting rid of content on the site (yes, I could and probably should just post a request on SOCVR but not all users are aware of it or active there)

Comment: It seems the mod flag was also in response to a declined NAA flag and was asking for a second look. Which is different than _just_ mod flagging immediately. (even if this can be handled by 20k+ users)

Comment: @HenryEcker I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that the mod flag was declined *because* of the declined NAA flag? That sounds.... unreasonable if it's true

Comment: @Tomerikoo no I was saying that a follow-up mod flag is more reasonable _after_ a declined NAA flag if you really believed it was NAA and that a mistake was made. That is different than mod flagging things that could be handled in queue. This was more in response to all of the comments saying a mod flag is incorrect. I have seen declined NAA flags followed up by mod flags which were marked helpful.

Comment: @HenryEcker Oh ok got it now. I was reading your first comment wrong... Thanks