# Should answers that are "completely off base" (i.e. the writer simply misread the question) just be deleted? How should we moderate them?

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-quality

Some questions are inherently very confusing and difficult.

Here for example is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11587287/294884) where the answerer missed the point (thinking it was something to do with how to enter a color as floats, whereas the question revolves around the fact that such and such feature doesn't work in such and such conditions).

I mean, there's 10 million (is that an accurate estimate?) "really delete-able for various reasons" answers on SO, but in this example, I was going to just flag it to the mods something like "completely misdirected answer adds further confusion on tricky QA..." but... I dunno.

Note that I'm NOT talking here about answers that - debatably or otherwise - are completely wrong technically. I'm thinking of answers that are hopelessly misdirected, just of no value (and indeed, almost certainly confusing to casual Googlers who see it).

What's the word on this? How should these kinds of answers be handled?

Note that, I've found typically, the answer-writer will often come back and delete such ephemera (which is great) but for answers so old the writer is possibly no longer active (a growing problem on SO) ... any thoughts?

Comment: btw i'm value neutral on this - I just want someone to tell me the norm.  ie do the mods want such flags or is it Not

Comment: In general, moderators are not SME's (Subject Matter Experts) and thus mostly have no basis to judge a flag that states that the answer is completely misdirected. Downvoting, commenting, and delete-voting are the most viable options.

Comment: @Luuklag: Also related to that question (it's linked in the comments of that question): [How to handle answers that are answers, but to a different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167235/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast that is also relevant, but that also contradicts with the stance that moderators are not SME's, and therefore might not be able to judge the value of a custom flag stating that it is an irrelevant answer (depending on how irrelevant an answer exactly is ofcourse.)

Comment: @Luuklag: Well, the *answers* might contradict those on the question you linked to – I was just linking to it because the question itself is related. :)

Answer (score 17):

Sure, but...the hope is that it's the *OP* that deletes them before the community has to.

You see, the problem with answer deletion that isn't your own is that it requires that the post be negatively scored.  This means for an answer that's upvoted N times, you have to get N+1 people to downvote it, and *then* you need two more people to swoop in behind you to also delete the post before someone else upvotes it again for Reasons™.

Diamond mods aren't likely going to delete an answer that they're simply told is way off-base, unless they also happen to be a subject matter expert.  Some are, but don't rely on the fact that some are that you'll get The One that is.

This is why it's a lot easier to try to convince the answerer to delete it.

So...best you can do?  Comment to let them know that this was way out in left field.  If you feel it's unhelpful, downvote it.  If the answerer insists otherwise, then don't get into a shouting match; your downvote will hopefully help get it closer to that threshold in which someone can remove the answer.

Comment: Hi - the elephant in the room is: *"the hope is that it's the OP that deletes them before the community has to"* In the overwhelming majority of cases described, the  answer-writer is deceased, or, a "passing user" from 10 or even 15 yrs ago who no longer has any interest in the site.  in the excptionally rare case of like "me" posting a wholly wrong answer, of course I immediately remove it; I actively edit and curate my answers.  os unfortunately the whole point here is "what to do in the (usual) case where you can't get the writer to delete it".

Comment: Say, I may totally misunderstand something.  Glance at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10719921/294884 notice it is negatively scored.  is there / should there now be a "delete" button??

Comment: Holy Smokes - a delete button just appeared.  I clicked it  :)

Comment: If that is the (unwritten?) policy then fine, but the wording on the **not an answer** flag is encouraging the flagging of answers that might require a SME: _"This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether"_. I can't be the only person who has wasted my time (and that of the mods) by pointlessly flagging truly irrelevant answers. Perhaps the wording accompanying the **not an answer** flag needs some work, clarifying when it should _not_ be used?

Comment: @skomisa The bar for NAA is so ridiculously high that it needs to be apparent to literally anyone, including your grandmother, that it's blatantly not an answer. In other words, if there's even a whiff of *an answer* to *a question* then any NAA flag seems likely to be declined. I've stopped flagging NAA and just comment and vote on content. It's really what you should be doing anyway like Makato suggests here. Mod flags should be reserved for things we can't moderate ourselves.  Or post on Meta and let the Meta-effect take effect. 

Comment: @Fattie the site didn't even *exist* 15 years ago (although it's getting close).  As for deleting my own answer, I'll often leave it so someone else doesn't make the same mistake, with a promise that I'll come back and clean it up later.  I'm sure I've forgotten that promise at least a couple of times.

Comment: @DrewReese No argument from me, but my point was that if the bar for NAA is _"ridiculously high"_ then the verbiage accompanying the **not an answer** flag should reflect that. As it stands that verbiage is openly encouraging the flagging of answers that may require an SME, which just wastes everyone's time.

Comment: @Fattie: Sure, but again you're faced with the N + 1 problem.  For content that old, you're probably better off simply downvoting and moving on. The weak signal the site had received is that, in spite of the answer being wrong, some people got value from it.

Comment: @skomisa I totally agree. You can only try so many times to use that flag and try so many times to complain about it for nothing to change. Seems the MODs and StackOverflow are ok with the verbiage. I've obviously moved on.

Comment: @skomisa: Yes, the wording of NAA is unhelpful and doesn't describe the actual conditions mods want it used in.  See [Not-an-answer flag declined on an answer that's clearly a comment on the programming language/CPU design, not an answer to any programming question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409213) for more discussion - they only want it used for trivial and obvious cases, not for a post that could be the answer to *some* question, just not this one.  (And they don't want any domain knowledge to be required to figure out if it could be an answer to any valid SO question.)

Comment: (That's fine and makes sense as a policy, it's just not reflected at all in the wording of the flagging dialog.)