# Should I flag blatantly off-topic answers?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

Sometimes I encounter answers that attempt to answer a question that is that completely unrelated to the parent question [(Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57709690). The example question is about Objective-C but the answer is about Flutter and Android Studio which are completely different things.

The answer is not necessarily 'incorrect' (I am aware we should not flag incorrect answers), but the answer is completely off-topic and unrelated to the question and does not belong. [This metapost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420337) seems to imply that 'off-topic' answers should be deleted. Should I flag these answers or just downvote?

This question is not about **wrong** or **unhelpful** answers in general, I am specifically asking about **off-topic** answers. I am also not asking specifically about **VLQ/NAA** flags, **custom flags** are not out of the question. My question was answered by @RyanM but not by any of the suggested duplicates.

Comment: @RobertLongson My question isn't about wrong answers or general answers that won't solve the problem. My question is **specifically** about answers that are altogether *unrelated* to the question. They do not attempt to answer the **question at hand**, but they may attempt to answer a completely different question.

Comment: So this then... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420404/should-answers-that-are-completely-off-base-i-e-the-writer-simply-misread-th?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Or maybe https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272925/are-answers-which-misunderstood-the-question-low-quality

Comment: That is a downvote reason, and delete vote reason, not a flag reason. In isolation a reviewer can't judge that an answer to **a** question isn't an answer to **the** question. And your flag is most likely to be handled by reviewers. And mods also start from the flag queue with the post in isolation, without context. Tricky business flagging those answers.

Comment: Some random observation - comment on the linked answer claims that Flutter can't be related to any Objective C code and that is immediately obvious to any reader. Since I knew nothing about either I decided to search which immediately resulted in https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=ios-channel-objective-c-tab "works directly with those APIs:... Swift or Objective-C on iOS". So I agree - there is no way for non-expert in Objective-C to know if that answer is related to the question or not.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov So maybe that answer should not be flagged.

Comment: @user16217248 I would not - there really no reason to ask moderators to do what regular users can do. If that answer would have +5 votes asking mods may be of some value, but at -4 plenty of people can delete that post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be reasonable to flag **very clear** instances of this with **custom flags containing an explanation of why** it doesn't answer the question, but definitely not as NAA/VLQ—we'll decline those pretty much every time. There are way too many posts that are flagged NAA/VLQ simply because they didn't help the flagger, and it's infeasible to spend the time to sort those out from legitimate gripes without any explanation.

"Very clear" means "it is obvious and not at all arguable to someone who is a programmer but not a subject-matter expert," because that's almost certainly who will be handling your flag.

For example, if someone posts a Java answer to a JavaScript question, you could flag that, explaining in the flag that it is Java code and the question is about JavaScript, and a moderator would likely delete that.

We will *not* delete:

- Answers that are simply wrong.  Even if they're *really* wrong.
- Frame challenges (e.g., "do this in JavaScript in the frontend like [code], not PHP in the backend").

Comment: *"There are way too many posts that are flagged NAA/VLQ simply because they didn't help the flagger, and it's infeasible to spend the time to sort those out from legitimate gripes without any explanation."* - Ah.  So that's why NAA is normally refused.  Makes sense.

Comment: Also some time ago I custom flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73884644/16217248) answer, which answers a C question in Python because they *'don't remember C.'* Why was that flag declined then?

Comment: Do you think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10563211) answer would be worthy of deletion?

Comment: @user16217248 For the first one: I wasn't the moderator that declined it, but perhaps it could be argued that they were explaining the algorithm using a Python example.  It's certainly not a *good* answer.  I've now deleted it, because I generally agree that it doesn't _really_ answer the question, and it used techniques that don't map to C.  For the second one: yes, with a note that the question asks for a storage _location_, and this does not even attempt to provide one.  I've also deleted that.