# Are Late Answers reviewers expected to verify the technical accuracy of answers?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, late-answers

Some time ago I failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/34009517) review audit. I was told to *Recommend Deletion* or *Edit* such posts. At the time I did not have full edit privileges and maybe the edit queue was full our I was out of edits.

While the code might not be correct, I do not really have a way to know besides executing the code and comparing to the expected results of the author, which I thought is beyond the time expected for reviewers, especially if the reviewer is not a field expert.

The answer was mostly code-only and not a good answer, but I have seen upvoted code-only answers on the site, so I would not *Recommend Deletion* purely on account of being code only. Also none of the canned *Recommend Deletion* comments include one about the answer being incorrect or code-only.

I thought wrong answers were handled by being downvoted and commented on by field experts who recognize them as wrong, and not be deleted or flagged/recommended for deletion.

Am I misguided here, or is this a bad audit?

Are users reviewing Late Answers only expected to remove repeats or very low quality or non-answers? Or are we also expected to verify the technical accuracy of answers? Are we expected to execute the code to verify that the answer solves the problem?

Is it appropriate to *Looks OK* answers that have no clear quality issues but we cannot necessarily understand what they do?

Comment: If you didn't know whether the answer was fine then "Looks OK" seems like the wrong choice. You can still skip the review if you can't categorically say if it's OK or not.

Comment: @VLAZ It looked OK enough to me. If I were to skip all answers that looked like that to me I would be skipping all tasks that have code (a majority of the tasks), as I could never be sure if the code was correct without being a field expert. I thought the LAQ was for holding answers to certain quality standards (i.e., removing non-answers, link-only answers, etc.), not accuracy standards.

Comment: The purpose of the late answers queue isn't to determine correctness, rather, it's to determine whether or not it's a repeat of an existing answer, or even an answer at all. This was a rather poor audit, it was only chosen because a moderator acted on it.

Comment: "*It looked OK enough to me*" and yet "*I do not really have a way to know besides executing the code and comparing to the expected results of the author*"

Comment: @VLAZ But still, the purpose of LAQ is not to verify the accuracy of answers. It is to remove very low quality and non-answers.

Comment: this answer was both, technically. but i fail to see how a non SME would be able to determine that. It wasn't a repeat of an existing answer, and being code only alone isn't a reason for deletion. it was an answer to a different question entirely

Comment: To quote the queue description: *"Reviewing these posts makes sure that questions maintain quality answers and problematic answers get removed"* ... and what is the best quality we want? Yes, incorrect code-only answers.

Comment: @Tom The queue is more black and white than FAQ. *Looks OK* and *Recommend Deletion*. (And also *Edit* and *Other*). I would assume the *Recommend Deletion* guidance is the same as the *What should I flag for moderator/deletion?* guidance. I.e., [very clear cases of off-topic answers that a programmer but not a field expert could see](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420455/16217248), or link-only answers or *Me too* / *Thanks* / other non-answers. And **not** incorrect or code-only answers.

Comment: "*Review new answers on old questions. Watch for hidden gems, non-answers, and spam.*" is the description. There is a comment on the answer saying "*The question is about trimming whitespace from the end of the string. Your code doesn't answer the question.*" I understand the comment would not be visible on the review but it does suggest the answer doesn't belong. Note: I'm not at well-versed in C++. I can't be sure what the answer is doing but somebody with a gold badge in C++ thought it was wrong. I'd say in that case it shouldn't Look OK if you can't actually understand the answer.

Comment: @VLAZ Then I would skip almost all answers because almost all answers are code solutions with technologies that I am not familiar with. My question is basically: *Are LAQ reviewers expected to go out of there way to verify the technical accuracy of answers?* I think not. Kevin B thinks not. You think yes. What do the staff/moderators think?

Comment: *"The queue is more black and white than FAQ. Looks OK and Recommend Deletion. (And also Edit and Other)."* ... you didn't why an Option like "Other" exists? Why the queue allows you to vote on the answer or even write a comments? Edit and Other aren't just useless non-options to have a fuller list, those are valid options to use as well.

Comment: @Tom Maybe I should have commented asking for more details. But I still think it is a poor audit.

Comment: *"Then I would skip almost all answers because almost all answers are code solutions with technologies that I am not familiar with."* ... Then use the tag filter

Comment: "The answer was mostly code-only and not a good answer" - So why did you pick "looks ok" in that case?  "Looks ok" is meant for contributions that are actually "ok" not a "code only answer that answers a completely different question that wasn't even asked".  If you downvoted the unhelpful "code only" answer (since it didn't answer the author's question) and choose "other action", you would have passed the audit.  As to the reason you failed, you indicated that a deleted answer, required no additional work, the fact it was deleted says that wasn't the case. I see nothing wrong with that audit.

Comment: @SecurityHound I don't downvote every code only answer I see; I sometimes see upvoted code-only answers. Without knowing whether the code is relevant or not, I just picked *Looks OK* (which was formerly called *No action needed*) as there are no clear other problems with the answer.

Comment: @user16217248 - Except this answer wasn't upvoted.  It was deleted.  It also didn't actually answer the author's question.  You don't need to be an expert on the topic to determine that fact.

Comment: @SecurityHound That one was not upvoted, sure, but some are. Given that not all code only answers are worthy of deletions, I choose *Looks OK* unless there are other problems with the answer. If I did not know C++, I would have no way to determine that it did not answer the question. It was a C++ answer to a C++ question, and it was not clearly a duplicate of the existing answers. Aside from knowing C++ or manually running the code, I would have no way of knowing that the answer is incorrect.

Comment: We clearly won't agree that the answer you reviewed made absolutely no attempt to answer what the question asked. It helps if you open the question in another tab.

Comment: @SecurityHound The question is about trimming a string in C++. The answer is in C++ and appears to be about string manipulation so it looks like a feasible answer. It was not, how was I as a reviewer supposed to know that without actually trying to understand the technical workings of the code, which is not feasible if I am reviewing answers to which I am not a subject-matter expert? By the way on that very same question there are answers that are upvoted that are nearly all-code.

Comment: Separately from how you should have answered it, on which I'm not expressing an opinion either way, I'm lifting the review suspension due to it being at least 
questionable (some support for both positions in the comments here) and because you've sought and engaged with feedback in an effort to review well (also it was the only addition to a previous auto-suspension, and the posts for which that was issued are also pretty questionable...I undeleted one of them).

Comment: @RyanM For the one you undeleted, looks like someone else even *Looks OK*ed it in LQA.

Comment: Yep.  I don't think it should've been deleted, and I think "Looks OK" was the right result for LQA.  Arguably in LA a comment like the one that it has would be good, but...ehhh, not really required.  Upgrading to a verified working version _is_ a solution.

Comment: I would recommend deletion purely on the basis that the question title is "How to trim an std::string?" and there are 51 undeleted answers.

Comment: @Tom I agree with you, but official moderation policy for the site "working together to build a library of *detailed, high-quality* answers" is **explicitly not** to remove content simply because it is incorrect (or needlessly complex, or insecure, etc.). They *won't even remove duplicates* if they happen to have been posted immediately when the question was asked, even though everyone agrees that the people jumping the gun to answer bad questions quickly are harming the site. There is *definitely* no expectation that moderation is done by someone with relevant expertise.

Comment: (In case I somehow failed to convey my tone: yes, this angers me, and I wish to see it change.)